# Python. Как брать данные из тестового файла?

Tags: python

Как сделать, чтобы в переменную "word", брались строки из текстового файла автоматически? После обработки первой строки, выводится результат, записывается в файл, и затем все повторяется со второй, третьей и т.д. строчкой.

```
__author__ = 'xcbtrader'
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from bitcoin import *

def crear_addr_word(word):
    priv = sha256(word)
    pub = privtopub(priv)
    addr = pubtoaddr(pub)
    wif = encode_privkey(priv, 'wif')
    return addr, priv, wif

word = input('Ведите фразу')
addr, priv, wif = crear_addr_word(word)
print('####################################################')
print('WORD: ' + word)
print('ADDR: ' + addr)
print('PRIV: ' + priv)
print('WIF: ' + wif)
print('####################################################')
```

Comment: `coding: utf-8` лучше на самом верху( после `#!`-строчки если есть) указывать. Хотя на Питоне 3 эту строку вообще можно не указывать (utf-8 это значение по умолчанию для кодировки исходного кода)

Comment: @jfs, просто нужно понимать что копировать https://github.com/xcbtrader/bitcoin-address/blob/master/addr-word.py :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with open('фразы.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        word = line.strip()
        if not word or word.startswith('#'):  # skip blank lines and comments
            continue
        addr, priv, wif = crear_addr_word(word)
        ...
```

Этот код предполагает, что текст в файле закодирован, используя `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` (к примеру, cp1251 на русской Windows или utf-8 на других настольных системах). Если это не так, то явно передайте encoding аргумент.

Comment: В вашем примере скрипт отрабатывает только самую последнюю строчку из файла и останавливается.

Comment: Я просто удалил: word = input('Ведите фразу') и заменил на ваш вариант.

Comment: код читает каждую строчку, кроме пустых и комментариев (начинаются с `#`).  Возьмите входной файл из **двух** (не более строчек) и замените в моём коде строчку с `crear_addr_word` на просто `print(word)`. Многоточие (и далее если у вас код идёт) сотрите. Если этот код напечатает только последнюю строчку, тогда обновите вопрос и добавьте туда код с `print()` и соответствующий входной файл

Comment: Скрипт напечатал обе строчки.

Comment: Получается мой скрипт видит все строчки, но берет в работу только последнюю почему то.

Comment: @Юрий так как кода вашего я не вижу, то могу предположить/предcказать, что вы забыли код внутрь цикла вставить (в Питоне отступы имеют значение), поэтому ваш код во время цикла не выполняется (его там нет), а вы полняется *после* цикла с последним значением word из цикла.

Comment: Вот все файлы скрипта: https://yadi.sk/d/C6VkdGVQ3L9f4c

Comment: @Юрий я не вижу связи ни с вопросом в заголовке ни с моим ответом, который его адресует. Если у вас не получается код внутрь цикла поместить -- буквально только отступ добавить (ваш код на место многоточия в моём коде поставить), то задайте отдельный вопрос специально об этом.

Comment: Я изменил код в вопросе. Этот вариант выводит результат обработки только последней строчки из файла 123.txt

Comment: Не изменяйте вопрос так, что это делает существующие ответы неверными. Если вы новый не хотите вопрос задать (о значении отступов в Питоне), то следовало бы в самом конце вопроса ваш код добавить (с замечанием: "попробовал [ответ @jfs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/693391/23044), получил то-то, а ожидал в это")

Comment: Ну я хоть правильно код изменил?

Comment: @Юрий нет. Как вы думаете что я имел в виду говоря об отступах в предыдущих комментариях?

Comment: Фуух. Наконец-то получилось. Никогда бы не подумал, что отступы такую роль играют. Огромное спасибо. Все работает.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open

```
with open('yourfile.txt', 'rt') as f:
   for line in f:
       print(line)
       do_what_you_want(line)
       ...
```

Имейте в виду, что строки считаются, включая символ перевода строки (`\r\n` для Windows), чтобы убрать их, используйте `line.rstrip('\n')` или `line.rstrip()` - чтобы убрать все завершающие пробельные символы.

Comment: У автора Питон 3 скрипт (по наличию input() вызова для простого текста). 'rt' не нужно на Python 3 (а на Python 2 это имело смысл вероятно только на Windows)

Comment: 'rt' и на 2-ом питоне по умолчанию ставится, но я предпочитаю указывать явно почти всегда.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, как вставить этот код в мой пример.

Comment: `mode == 'r'` по умолчанию в Питоне. `'t'` (если вы его явно укажите)  СPython 2 передаёт в C stdio fopen ([в C не определён такой mode](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen), но большинство платформ вероятно не сломаются). На Питоне 3, если `'b'` не указан, то`'t'`  подразумевается. Нет никакой необходимости `'t'` передавать, если не пытаться эксплуатировать какое-то специфичное для платформы поведение.