# Неверная кодировка при записи в файл

Tags: python

```
def replace_line(file_name, line_num, text):
    lines = open(file_name, 'r').readlines()
    lines[line_num] = text
    out = open(file_name, 'w')
    out.writelines(lines)
    out.close()

replace_line('filename.py',200, 'Что-то на русском')
```

В файле пишет �������. Кодировка файла utf-8

Comment: 1 - проверьте, что open у вас открывает файл с кодировкой utf-8 (под Windows он по-умолчанию скорее всего откроет с кодировкой cp1251). Соответственно и на запись файл должен открываться с кодировкой utf-8. 2 - возможно ваш текстовый редактор (или чем вы открываете готовый файл) не поддерживает utf-8. Или по-умолчанию в нем выбрана другая кодировка. Или кодировка файла (исходного и готового) другая.

Comment: связанный вопрос [Python. Как брать данные из тестового файла?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/693368/23044)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вторая строчка:

```
lines = open(file_name, 'r', encoding='utf-8').readlines()
```

Попробуйте так, на Windows кодировка обычно cp1251

Answer (score 2):

Спасибо, проблема решена. Заменил эти строчки

```
lines = open(file_name, 'r', encoding='utf-8').readlines()
out = open(file_name, 'w',encoding="utf-8")
```